# Validating a text file with header, detail and trailer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an input text file with a header line, follow by multiple detail record lines, and follow by a trailer line. The format is something line this:

```
H20150225
DABC....
DDEF.....
T20150225 000002
```

I need to write a program to perform the following on this input file:

(1) The header must start with 'H' and follow by a date in the format YYYYMMDD. This date must be current date - 1 days (that is, yesterday's date).

(2) The detail record lines must start with a 'D'.

(3) The trailer must start with a 'T' and follow by a date in the format YYYYMMDD. This date must be the same as the date in the header.

(4) There is a count in the trailer (after the date follow by a space), and this count must be equal to the number of detail records in the file.

(5) All the lines in the file must be of the same length of N characters long.

(6) After the validation, output the contents of this file into an output file. The output file will exclude both the header and trailer. For each detail record line in the file, the first letter 'D' should be omitted.

It would be easy writing in a programming language like Java, but can this be accomplished using just a Windows batch script?

Comment: I'm going to need to see some sample output...

Comment: Based on the above sample input file, the output file will have just two lines. First line is "ABC...." and second line  is "DEF....". There is no more header and  trailer, and the leading 'D' in front of each detail is stripped.

Comment: yes, it can be acomplished with a Windows batch script. You'll need a `FOR` loop and some `IF` logic. Try it and come back with more specific questions.